# Labeling composite entities in LUIS isn't working

Tags: botframework, azure-language-understanding

I'm trying to have LUIS recognize something pretty straight forward: "2 waters" So I

1. Set up the number built in entity
2. Created a list entity which contains among its members the word water
3. Created a composite entity which holds both, the number and the list entities

Then I go and test the intent with utterances that involve the words "2 waters" and it does recognize the number and list entities but separately, and doesn't allow me to compound it into their parent composite at the same time (only separately).

[image]

Comment: The best approach is to wrap the existing entities in a composite that you create at that time -- do not create composites before -- it helps illustrate what the composite label does.

Comment: mm i dont think you can create a composite before you create the children entities first.. so that should be already the case. or am i missing something?

Answer (score 3):

Okay, This is really embarassing but I was facing the same issue until I read up the help documents. 
What I was doing involved -

1. Select the first entity, Right click -> Wrap .... -> Select the
   composite entity
2. Select the second entity, Rinse repeat.
3. See that the two entities are wrapped separately, scratch my head in
   confusion

After I read the Help documents, These are the steps I followed which worked -

1. Select the first entity, Right click -> Wrap in Composite Entity
2. Without clicking on the composite entity, move the mouse cursor over
   the second entity and click ! this underlines both of them in Green.
3. THEN, select the composite entity and viola ! problem solved

Comment: I actually figured it out a few days ago and was about to post the answer but didn't have a chance.. you've got it! :)

Comment: I'm trying to do the same thing, but right click brings up the browser right click context menu, not the portal context menu.  How do you do this?

Comment: @PatrickGoode - I guess the UI has changed since the answer was posted. Just left click and move the mouse over all the words you want wrapped as part of the composite entity

Comment: @Arun thanks, I've found the new preview portal is much easier

Answer (score 1):

> it does recognize the number and list entities but separately

I create a luis app and do a test in **Test panel**, I can reproduce the issue: getting child entities (`number` and `object`) and composite entity (`mytesttntity`) separately.

[image]

If I access published endpoint with same test query/utterance, I find the composite entity in returned response. You can try to make a request to your published endpoint and check if it can return an expected response.

[image]

Comment: Interesting.. I did check for the returned objects and didn't see it.. Also, I would think the Composite Entities would return on the CompositeEntities array and not embedded on the Entities list. It seems like it's a platform bug.. Good to know though. Thanks!

Comment: I'm facing the same issue, but even the published endpoint does not return the correct results. I did manage to link two entities as composite for one utterance but for the rest it's still not working even though they are very similar